# Typescript can't correctly infer type of parameter inside function overload

Tags: typescript, overloading, discriminated-union

When calling function foo the correct types are enforced but inside the function i would expect that inside the if statement typescript would correctly infer that age is a string when name equals "a". Is there another way to do this?

```
function foo(name: "a", age: string): void;
function foo(name: "b", age: number): void;
function foo(name: "a" | "b", age: string | number) {
  if (name === "a") {
     const x = age; // Would expect x to be string but is string | number;
  }
}
foo("a", "asd"); // Correct
foo("a", 5); // Error
foo("b", 5); // Correct
foo("b", "asd"); // Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into this problem all the time and it is why I try to avoid function overloads in TypeScript. This isn't really how they work, since there is just one implementation the TS compiler doesn't discriminate the function arguments. I imagine this has to do with backwards-compatibility but it sure is a pain.

The only workaround I have found is explicitly using discriminated unions in the function signature--but this requires defining the arguments as spread.

```typescript
function foo(...[name, age]: [name: "a", age: string] | [name: "b", age: number]) {
  if (name === "a") {
    const x = age;
    //    ^? const x: string
  }
  if (name === "b") {
    const x = age; 
    //    ^? const x: number
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA6LBtMBDAWwFMAaRPAcyIF0AuRXQo+gIjxbMucQGcoAnGGArVEAHwb5irAEYdyVemBAEZRftQCUiAN4AoRIhjBEaKUUQBea4jYtt+w4YgI+iAB5WFRANwGnAPQBTogAegD8iC5gbu70fILC-gC+-sam5lY2LHIO-s6uUB5eXD6I+YhBIRFRhR5KKmr8KXqpKOh2ZGw8ACb2ZVUAwnD8-ETQeu1onYgArJoDwQCioyOTqNNyZPOLiMOj41DrHVu2eL39lcur-EA)

I don't know of any issue on the TypeScript GitHub that addresses this but there may be one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer jacob! I just tried an alternative example in playground with your same exact logic but instead of "a" i used string and instead of "b"i used number. So i did if (typeof name === "string") and it didn't work. But with name === "a" it works. Weird.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos That is quite odd, I guess the compiler is struggling to discriminate `[string, string]` from `[number, number]`. I don't really understand it though. I thought I knew my stuff when it came to TS types but this is really throwing me off!